# Asynchronously Load the Contents of a Full Div

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to asynchronously load the contents of a whole div. so far, I'm preloading the div .orbit-wrapper, but only the background images load async. Id like to delay loading of everything in that div until the page has fully loaded. ideally, with an ajax-loader.gif as the background http://d.pr/DvKV

Comment: Use jQuery ajax,or jQuery post or jQuery load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery [Ajax.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is your friend. I copied the example directly from jQuery documentation. See below:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

This will put #container from test.html in your current page's #result.

Comment: Hi HungryCoder, and thanks. I just tried     <script>
 $('#home_conta').load(<?php "'" . get_template_directory() . '/loop-slideshow.php' . " #featured'" ?>);
</script> on http://theplural.com/ . I cant tell if it's working

Answer (score -1):

Here i send you example for asynchronously load the contents of a whole div and it is also useful for all div in page just set "data-url" for each div and give class name "partialContents"

```
<div class="partialContents" data-url="Your-URL">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

            var baseUrl = window.location.origin;//Load base URL

            $(".partialContents").each(function (index, item) {
                var url = baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
                if (url && url.length > 0) {
                    $(item).load(url);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: how is this more async then accepted answer?